# Java File явно указать кодировку

Tags: java, кодировка, javafx

Загружаю средствами `java.io.File` текстовый файл UTF-8 с буквами/цифрами. Пока запускаю из IDE непосредственно - все нормально - и читает и пишет.

После публикации в jar или exe перестают понимать UTF, но при этом корректно работает с ANSI. При этом приложение, запущенное из IDE не переваривает ANSI.
Можно как то явно кодировку указывать при загрузке/сохранении?

ЗЫ: Все происходит в приложении javaFX, если это важно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У `java.io.File` кодировку указать не получится.

Явно указать кодировку, можно, например, в конструкторе `InputStreamReader`:

```
InputStreamReader(InputStream in, String charsetName)
```

и в конструкторе `OutputStreamWriter`:

```
OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream out, String charsetName)
```

**Пример для чтения:**

```
File file = new File("test.txt");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF8"));
```

**Пример для записи:**

```
File file = new File("test.txt");
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF8"));
```